# Get Current User's Colleagues Using JSOM

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, client-object-model

Is there a way to retrieve the currently logged in user's colleagues' usernames?

I found [this](http://spdailytips.blogspot.co.uk/2011/09/get-user-colleagues-with-sharepoint.html) which shows how to do it using server object model, but haven't found anything for JavaScript object model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might be wrong, but isnt Colleagues the same as SPS-Peers? If so you could get it with UserProfiles.

Example:

```
function getPeers() {
    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var peopleManager = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(context);
    userProfileProperties = peopleManager.getMyProperties();
    context.load(userProfileProperties, 'Peers');
    context.executeQueryAsync(success, fail);
}
function success(){
  var peers = userProfileProperties.get_peers();
  console && console.dir(peers);
}

function fail(sender, args) {
 console && console.log("Error");
}


SP.SOD.loadMultiple(['sp.js', 'userprofile'],function() {
 getPeers();
});
```

Comment: Hmm.. an interesting idea, according to this https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/Work-with-the-colleagues-list-on-My-Site-d19240af-54de-4a99-b5b8-fb9181149b39?ui=en-US&rs=en-SG&ad=SG&fromAR=1 My Colleagues category includes your manager, your peers, and your direct reports

Comment: @VadimGremyachev So if one includes the Properties; DirectReports/ExtendedReports and ExtendedManagers you would have the same result

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I'll give it a try and get back.

Comment: So this solution seems to work. However, I don't get back ALL of the user's colleagues, as setup in Active Directory. I have a feeling this is possibly because they don't all have user profiles on SharePoint as some have not yet logged onto our new SharePoint site - what do you think? Any way to get around this so that all colleagues are returned regardless of whether they have a user profile on SharePoint or not? Thanks.

Comment: @Submits I don't think you can get all the Peers without syncing all the Users. They don't have to be logged in for the Profile to be created, just mysite is created the first time they click on about me. Do you see the missing people in the UserProfile Service if you search for AD-users there? If not, make sure you sync all the users to the User Profile Service.

Comment: @AndersAune I confirmed this behaviour today by having a user log on to the SharePoint site that had not logged on before and sure enough this user now shows up in the list of peers. I have User Profile Sync set up already but it does not pull in all AD users as you suggested. Any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it does **not** seem possible to archive via SharePoint CSOM/JSOM API since SSOM [ColleagueManager class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.userprofiles.colleaguemanager.aspx) is **not** supported in CSOM/JSOM API.

But you could utilize [SharePoint Web Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj193051.aspx), in particular [UserProfileService.GetUserColleagues method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/websvcuserprofileservice.userprofileservice.getusercolleagues.aspx) for that purpose:

SPServices example:

```
$().SPServices({
    operation: "GetUserColleagues", 
    AccountName: $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({fieldName: "Name"}), 
    completefunc:function(data,status) {
        //process GetUserColleaguesResult... 
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I shall give it a try and get back.

Comment: I prefer the answer by Anders on this occasion as it does not require the use of SPServices. Many thanks for your help.